# binomial inequality with sums

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients

Assume I have a series of numbers $a_1 \dots a_n$ where $0 \leq a_i \leq n-1$ and a positive integer $r$.

how to show that the sum of number of ways to choose $r$ from $a_i$ is at least as $n$ times the number of ways to choose $r$ from the average of $a_i$'s.

in other words, I need to show:

$$\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}\binom{a_i}r\geq n\binom{\frac1n\sum_{1\le i\le n}a_i}r $$

any idea of how to prove this? if you think it is not correct, which conditions do I need to add to make it correct?

Comment: You can get a real binomial coefficient with `\binom{a_i}{r}`, for instance.

Comment: thanks for your editing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is correct if $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ is a multiple of $n$. Let $a=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^na_i$; we want to show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{a_i}r\ge n\binom{a}r\;.\tag{1}$$

Suppose that $a_i<a<a_k$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{a_i}r+\binom{a_k}r&=\binom{a_i}r+\binom{a_k-1}r+\binom{a_k-1}{r-1}\\
&\ge\binom{a_i}r+\binom{a_k-1}r+\binom{a_i}{r-1}\\
&=\binom{a_i+1}r+\binom{a_k-1}r\;.
\end{align*}$$

Repeatedly transferring a unit from an $a_k>a$ to an $a_i<a$ will eventually convert the $n$-tuple $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ to the constant $n$-tuple $\langle a,\ldots,a\rangle$, and no transfer increases the sum of the binomial coefficients, so $(1)$ holds.

More generally, the same argument shows that if we hold $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ constant, $\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{a_i}r$ is minimized when the integers $a_i$ are as nearly equal as possible. If the sum is a multiple of $n$, this is when all $n$ are equal; otherwise, if the sum is $qn+s$ for integers $q$ and $s$ such that $0\le s<n$, it occurs when $s$ of the $a_i$ are equal to $q+1$ and the rest to $q$.

Comment: Thanks a lot... but I'm not sure you need to require that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ is a multiple of $n$ ... your argument is based on that: $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - a) = 0$ , but this is correct because $a$ is the average. right?

Comment: @Mahmoud: Yes, $a$ is the average, but in order for it to be an integer, the sum must be a multiple of $n$.

Comment: yes you are right... I just noticed that now. thanks again :)

Comment: @Mahmoud: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott  The binomial coefficient is well defined for non-integer upper parameter (but not for non-integer lower parameter). So it appears that the proof given is valid without the restriction to the average being an integer.

Comment: @Mark: The binomial coefficient is still defined, but the argument doesn’t go through.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Doesn't the usual trick done in Concrete Mathematics, of noting that two polynomials of degree $k$ which agree at more than $k$ points are identical, let you rescue the argument?

Comment: @Mark: I don’t see how: the argument shows that you can shift one unit from a term larger than the average to one smaller than the average, but repetitions of that operation won’t let you reach the average unless it differs from the original term by an integer.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: You are right. The argument usually goes "here are two polynomials of degree $r$ and they agree at more than $r$ (integer) points, so they must be identical everywhere. Here, they don't agree at the integer points, the one is $\leq$ the other. So the argument does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another solution using Jensen's inequality.

define:

$$f(x) = \frac{x(x-1)\dots (x-r+1)}{r!} =: \binom{x}{r}$$
$$ p_i = \frac{1}n$$

$f$ is convex for positive $x$. Pay attention that $r$ is a given constant.

Using Jensen's inequality gives:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n p_i f(a_i) \geq f\left( \sum_{i=1}^n p_i a_i \right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}n \binom{a_i}{r} \geq \binom{ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} a_i}{r} $$

multiplying by $n$ gives the needed result.